odoo field Html loop
I have field HTML in odoo , which looks like in localhost:

Frutas:
Apple 100 piece
Banana 20 pieces
Avocado 1 piece
in template on localhost

my fields in models and view is:
frutas = fields.Html(compute="get_diagram_1", store=True)


 <field name="frutas" widget="html"
options="{'editable': False}"/>


I want to set each name of fruit a type='object' name='list_fruits' by id. This function I have , but I dont understand how to in xml set a type='object' name='list_fruits' for each name to click .

Maybe somebody understand how loop each element in field and set action button or maybe other ways to choose another type of field and put context as a list with buttons.
